# Can't send POST request to my basic FLASK Python application

Tags: python, flask, httprequest, http-method

I am trying to test the basic HTTP requests in my simple rest api using Flask framework in Python. The GET method worked just fine not the POST method yet. here is the route:

```
@app.route('/lang', methods=['POST'])
def addOne():
    language = {'name' : request.json['name']}
    languages.append(language)
    return jsonify({'languages' : languages})
```

My languages dictionary:

```
languages = [{'name' : 'JavaScript'},{'name' : 'Java'}, {'name' : 'Python'}]
```

I am trying to use Postman application to post a new language to the dictionary, here is the request:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8080/lang
```

And in the body, row I placed this:

```
{"name" : "C++"}
```

It gives me this error:

```
  File "/home/pi/IoT_api/restful.py", line 22, in addOne
    language = {'name' : request.json['name']}
TypeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

Comment: Did you tell postman to send a JSON content type header?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Yes

Comment: What headers are you sending?

Comment: @JimWright application/json

Comment: Content-Type: application/json?

Answer (score 1):

The [documentation](http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/0.12/api/#flask.Request.json) clearly says:

> If the mimetype is application/json this will contain the parsed JSON data. Otherwise this will be None.

So make sure to correctly define the 'Content-Type' header with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/docs/postman/sending_api_requests/requests#headers)

Answer (score 0):

with the new flask version, change how you get post data from

> ```
> language = {'name' : request.json['name']}
> ```

to

> language = request.get_json('name')